# Not able to get slot values from user

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I stuck in a issue, where I have to fill all slots from user.

Sharing required details -

I used Lex for writing Bot and intent Definition.

I exported Lex configuration to Alexa Skill kit.

Currently, I am facing issue, while fetching values of all slots of given intent from user.

**Lambda code snippet -**

```
@Override
public SpeechletResponse onIntent(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<IntentRequest> speechletRequestEnvelope) {

    IntentRequest request = speechletRequestEnvelope.getRequest();

    Session session = speechletRequestEnvelope.getSession();

    log.info(String.format("onIntent. requestId : %s, sessionId : %s, Intent : %s", request.getRequestId(),
            speechletRequestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId(), speechletRequestEnvelope.getRequest().getIntent()));

    Intent intent = request.getIntent();

    String intentName = (intent != null) ? intent.getName() : null;

    if ("HelloWorldIntent".equals(intentName)) {
        return getHelloResponse();
    } else if ("AMAZON.HelpIntent".equals(intentName)) {
        return getHelpResponse();
    } else if (LMDTFYIntent.MissingDrivesComplaint.name().equals(intentName)) {
        return handleMissingDriveIntent(session, intent);
    } else {
        return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", "This is unsupported.  Please try something else.");
    }

}


private SpeechletResponse handleMissingDriveIntent(Session session, Intent intent) {

    log.info(String.format("Executing intent : %s. Slots : %s", intent.getName(), intent.getSlots()));

    Slot missingDriveSlot = intent.getSlot("missingDate");

    Slot missingDrivesCountSlot = intent.getSlot("missingDrivesCount");

    printSlots(intent.getSlots());

    if(missingDriveSlot == null || missingDriveSlot.getValue() == null) {

        printSlots(intent.getSlots());

        log.info(String.format("Missing Drives slot is  null"));

        //return handleMissingDriveDialogRequest(intent, session);

        ElicitSlotDirective elicitSlotDirective = new ElicitSlotDirective();
        elicitSlotDirective.setSlotToElicit("missingDate");

        SpeechletResponse speechletResponse = new SpeechletResponse();
        speechletResponse.setDirectives(Arrays.asList(elicitSlotDirective));

        SsmlOutputSpeech outputSpeech = new SsmlOutputSpeech();
        outputSpeech.setSsml("On which date drives were missing");
        speechletResponse.setOutputSpeech(outputSpeech);

        return speechletResponse;

    } else if(missingDrivesCountSlot == null || missingDrivesCountSlot.getValue() == null) {

        printSlots(intent.getSlots());

        log.info(String.format("Missing Drive Count is null"));

        // return handleMissingDrivesCountDialogRequest(intent, session);

        ElicitSlotDirective elicitSlotDirective = new ElicitSlotDirective();
        elicitSlotDirective.setSlotToElicit("missingDrivesCount");

        SpeechletResponse speechletResponse = new SpeechletResponse();
        speechletResponse.setDirectives(Arrays.asList(elicitSlotDirective));

        return speechletResponse;

    }  else if(missingDriveSlot.getValue() != null && missingDrivesCountSlot.getValue() != null) {

        printSlots(intent.getSlots());

        log.info(String.format("All slots filled."));

        SpeechletResponse speechletResponse = new SpeechletResponse();

        ConfirmIntentDirective confirmSlotDirective = new ConfirmIntentDirective();

        speechletResponse.setDirectives(Arrays.asList(confirmSlotDirective));

        return speechletResponse;

    } else {
        /*SpeechletResponse speechletResponse = new SpeechletResponse();


        speechletResponse.setDirectives(Arrays.asList());*/
    }

    return null;

}
```

**Check method -**

handleMissingDriveIntent

**Slots-**

missingDate

missingDrivesCount

Question-

1. Amazon Echo Dot is saying - "There were a problem with a requested skill response". How can I figure out the reason ?

Comment: please capture logs from cloud watch and update in your question

Answer (score 0):

> "There were a problem with a requested skill response"

Then Alexa responds to that error message back to you. That means there is a runtime error in your code.

You can check the CloudWatch logs from your lambda function (or using `ask cli` tool if you are using it). It can show you a line number where the error is happening. So you need to proceed from there.